# Can someone explain why this Ruby next if works in an until loop?

Tags: ruby

```
def sorting(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted 
    sorted = true
    arr.each_index do |i|
      next if i == arr.length - 1 
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end
  arr
end

p sorting([7, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3]) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

#### My question is: Why would the above Ruby code work?

First: When we called `sorted = true` right inside the `until` loop, that fulfills the condition of the sorted and it should end the loop.

Second: Can someone explain why the process of `next if` inside the iteration method won't continue to iterate the whole array, 
when it should have ended after the first iteration, and then call on `sorted = true`.

I was asked to explain, and I was wondering if anyone can provide a better explanation.

Thank you Ruby Masters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `until` is a top-testing loop.  The entire block must loop before the `until` condition is tested again; it is not tested after every statement within the loop.  You have to reach `end` or `next` before the `until` will evaluate again.

Second, `<statement> if <condition>` is a ruby shorthand for `if <condition> <statement> end`.  It allows you to write a simple conditional on one line without sacrificing readability.  The `next` will only execute at the last iteration of the `arr.each_index` loop, going up the stack to the `until` condition, by which time `sorted` will have been set to `false`.

To see how this works, try running the following modification:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def sorting(arr)
  puts "starting with #{arr}"
  sorted = false
  until sorted 
    sorted = true
    arr.each_index do |i|
      if i == arr.length - 1 
        puts "'next' when i == #{i}, arr = #{arr}"
        next
      end
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        puts "swapping at #{i}: #{arr[i]} <=> #{arr[i+1]}"
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
     end
   end
   arr
end

p sorting([7,4,5,1,2,3])
```

The output of this program is:

```
starting with [7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
swapping at 0: 7 <=> 4
swapping at 1: 7 <=> 5
swapping at 2: 7 <=> 1
swapping at 3: 7 <=> 2
swapping at 4: 7 <=> 3
'next' when i == 5, arr = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 7]
swapping at 1: 5 <=> 1
swapping at 2: 5 <=> 2
swapping at 3: 5 <=> 3
'next' when i == 5, arr = [4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
swapping at 0: 4 <=> 1
swapping at 1: 4 <=> 2
swapping at 2: 4 <=> 3
'next' when i == 5, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
'next' when i == 5, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

This is of course academic: the proper way to sort the array would be with [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-sort).

Note: the `next` is only necessary at all because on the last iteration of the `each_index` loop, `i + 1` will be out of range for the array, which would cause the next line which accesses `arr[i + 1]` to fail (it will evaluate to `nil`, and you can't compare an Integer to nil). Alternate ways of doing this would be to modify the conditional around the swap testing the index, or change the outside of the loop enumerating the array to be a smaller range.

Modifying the conditional, eliminating the `next`, which works because logical-and conditionals are evaluated left to right and the interpreter stops as soon as the first one is false:

```
def sorting(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted 
    sorted = true
    arr.each_index do |i|
      if (i < arr.size - 1) && (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
     end
   end
   arr
end

p sorting([7,4,5,1,2,3])
```

Changing the range of the loop, which is better in that the loop executes fewer times:

```
def sorting(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted 
    sorted = true
    (0..arr.size - 2).each do |i|
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
     end
   end
   arr
end

p sorting([7,4,5,1,2,3])
```

`next` is akin to `goto` in other languages and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the detail explanation. This makes a whole lot sense. I have one more question though: If I bring this line of code "sorted = true" inside the until loop, move it down to the line after the end of the iteration, the loop ends before it sorts completely. Is there a reason why this way it won't work?  
`def sorting(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted 
    (0..arr.size - 2).each do |i|
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
     end
     sorted = true
   end
   arr
end

p sorting([7,4,5,1,2,3])`

Comment: The idea behind the `sorted` variable is to operate as a flag that controls whether the `until` loop will execute again or not.  If you set `sorted` to true right before the end of the `until` loop, you are guaranteeing that the `until` loop will only execute once.  The `sorted = false` only happens *if* something happens to the array, there will be one final pass just to see that there's nothing to do.  You set it to true first, and then to false only if you need to.

Comment: Cool, thanks, Tom.  I just learned to this by nature but never actually thought about the difference nor why. I learned a good lesson this time! Thank you1